# Sending cut orchids from Singapore to Australia

Tags: legal, mail, victoria-australia

Can I send cut orchids from Singapore to someone in Australia?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about traveling

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see how this might be related to Travel.

Answer (score 2):

Australia has strict biological materials controls at customs and immigration. If you’re flying in, carrying some [flowers](http://www.agriculture.gov.au/import/goods/plant-products/cut-flowers-foliage) are permitted from some countries but you’ll need to declare them. Their postal service on the other hand might refuse to import biologicals without an import/export certificate.

It’d be infinitely easier and less expensive to just go online or phone the nearest florist to your recipient and order orchids there.

Comment: FWIW I have carried in Orchids into Australia that I bought in the airport in Bangkok and the customs process is very straight forward.  They have seen it all before and and I was through customs in no time at all.